# Transfer a file from AS400 to another machine in the same network

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I am trying to export the data of a table on AS400 to another machine through iSeries commands but I am stacked in the middle of the process. I have a stored procedure in which I create the CSV file but after completion I need to transfer this file to another machine (which is of course connected to the AS400).

In the stored procedure, I used the `CPYTOIMPF` command to export table data to CSV and I wrote the file on the AS400 file system. I don't know if there is an option to write the file directly to another machine.

```
CALL QSYS2.QCMDEXC(
 'CPYTOIMPF FROMFILE(LIBRARY/TABLE) TOSTMF('/QIBM/UserData/TestFolder/2.CSV') STMFCODPAG(*PCASCII) RCDDLM(*CRLF)'
);
```

This step is completed and the file is written on that directory.

Now I need to transfer this file to a web server that is connected to AS400 without after the above command is completed.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the operating-system of the other machine?

Comment: windows server 2008 R2

Comment: So you question is how to do programmed file-transfer between AS400 (i-series) and Windows-server?   Do you plan for the i-series box to PUSH the file to Windows, or Windows to PULL the file from i-series?  Consider SFTP (If Windows-server runs a service for it) if you want i-series to be doing the push.

Comment: It's better if the i-series machine PUSH the file to the windows server, otherwise i'll need to monitor when the generation of the CSV file is completed.

Comment: Is the web server on the same network as IBM i, or is there a firewall between them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FTP on IBM i. Here is a modified example from the [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaiq/rzaiqbatchftpsim.htm)

This is a CL program

```
PGM 
  OVRDBF   FILE(INPUT) TOFILE(MYLIB/QCLSRC) MBR(FTPCMDS) 
  OVRDBF   FILE(OUTPUT) TOFILE(MYLIB/QCLSRC) MBR(OUT) 
  FTP      RMTSYS(SYSxxx) 
ENDPGM
```

This program overrides the input of the FTP client to a script in `MYLIB/QCLSRC` member `FTPCMDS`, and the output of the FTP client to `MYLIB/QCLSRC` member `OUT`. The first line of the script must contain the userid and password for the remote location.

Here is a sample script from the same Knowledge Center reference:

```
ITSO ITSO    <== This is the user id and password
CD ITSOLIB1 
SYSCMD CHGCURLIB ITSOLIB2 
GET QCLSRC.BATCHFTP QCLSRC.BATCHFTP (REPLACE 
QUIT
```

This should not be used outside your network as the user id an password are sent in plain text. It also can be a security risk as production user id's and passwords must be stored in plain text in the source file.

---

In addition, Scott Klement has a presentation on how to use `ssh`, `scp`, and `sftp` on IBM i. This is quite a long thing, so you might want to read about it [here](http://www.scottklement.com/presentations/Setting%20up%20and%20Scripting%20the%20OpenSSH,%20SFTP%20and%20SCP%20Utilities%20on%20IBM%20i.pdf).

A short summary is that `scp` might be the easiest way to go. but you will need to:

1. Make sure that OpenSSH option of the OS is installed.
2. Make sure your Windows server is set up as an ssh server.
3. Set up a digital key to use for the transfer. Private key goes on client side, and public key goes on server side.
4. Use `scp fromfile user@host:tofile` in Pase to transfer the file.